# How can i used google drive api v3 to upload a file to shared drive

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to upload a file to my shared drive using drive API v3
it works fine with normal drive ids, but when I put shared drive ids, it fails to work.
my code :-

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import argparse
import json
import mimetypes
import os.path
import requests

script_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
script_dir = os.path.dirname(script_path)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('file', metavar='FILE')
parser.add_argument('folder', metavar='FOLDER_ID')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()

file_path = args.file
file_obj = open(file_path, mode='rb')
file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
file_mime_type = mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)[0]


### client secret ###

client = None
client_name = 'client_secret.json'
client_path = os.path.join(script_dir, client_name)
with open(client_path, 'r') as f:
    client = json.load(f)
assert client is not None and 'installed' in client
client = client['installed']

assert 'client_id' in client
if args.verbose:
    print('=== client id ===')
    print(client['client_id'])
    print()

assert 'client_secret' in client
if args.verbose:
    print('=== client secret ===')
    print(client['client_secret'])
    print()


### refresh token ###

refresh_token = None
refresh_name = 'refresh_token.txt'
refresh_path = os.path.join(script_dir, refresh_name)
with open(refresh_path, mode='r') as f:
    refresh_token = f.read().rstrip()

if args.verbose:
    print('=== refresh token ===')
    print(refresh_token)
    print()


### access token ###

r = requests.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', data={
    'client_id': client['client_id'],
    'client_secret': client['client_secret'],
    'refresh_token': refresh_token,
    'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
})
r = r.json()
assert 'error' not in r, r['error_description']

access_token = r['access_token']
if args.verbose:
    print('=== access token ===')
    print(access_token)
    print()


### upload file ###

r = requests.post('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart', files={
    'metadata': (
        None,       json.dumps({
            'name': file_name,
            'parents': [
                args.folder,
            ],
        }),
        'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    ),
    'file': (
        file_name,
        file_obj,
        file_mime_type,
    ),
}, headers={
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
})
r = r.json()
assert 'error' not in r, '{} - {}'.format(r['error']['code'], r['error']['message'])

if args.verbose:
    print('=== file id ===')
    print(r['id'])
    print()
```

(sorry for messy code file handling is messy)
I cant find any documentation which helps to create requests for shared drives
I just want it to work when I put a shared drive id as well
please suggest changes :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out all i had to do was put "&supportsAllDrives=true" after "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart"